# without override current value how to add new value in attr tag

Tags: jquery, css, position, attr

i want to know that without override in current value how to add new value in `attr` tag i know it's a typical question but am asking only value in numeric let me explain
i have a `ul` like this

```
<ul id="carousel" style="width: 5400px; right: -1800px; position: absolute;">
```

now what i want i run a function on

```
setInterval(function(){ulAnimate()},200)

ul.animate({left:'-=150px'} ,opts.speed ,function(){
  ul.css(optionObjRev);
  makeClone();
});
```

this function moves `ul` position 
when this function run it ruined old position given by default 
i just want it will not ruined old position and add this value in default value

take a look this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/AkyXK/

thanks

Comment: You are not adding a new property to it.You are just modifying an existing property.It would be nice if you could be a bit more clear on what you actually want.

Comment: can you show me how to do that